# How to compute spatial relationships from bounding boxes?

Tags: java, geometry, computational-geometry, graphics2d, jts

Let's say that I have an image with some kind of figures in it. An user can select 2 of them by drawing a bounding box around a figure. What I would like to do is to compute various spatial relationships between these 2 bounding boxes (so 2 rectangles) like: horizontal, vertical, diagonal, near, far, overlap, contains etc...

I have to do it in java.

I already know the existance of this library:
http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm

But I am not sure that it can help me with relationships such as horizontal, vertical, diagonal, near and far. Maybe it could help with overlap and contains.

**What I want to ask is if there is some theory to know to tackle this problem** before I start coding some kind of ad hoc implementation (of course I have ideas on how to implement that relations, but maybe there is something I should know).

Comment: About "maybe help" with overlap and contains operations, I can assure you JTS has support to several operations like these. It includes the "intersection" and "contains" operations on its "Geometry" class. http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html

Comment: Hmm, looking again through your question, it also has operations for distance (so you can decide what is near of far). And it also has "horizontal" and "vertical" predicates for line segments (in a class called LineSegment) which might help you.

Comment: And... Maybe JTS is an overkill solution for your case. As a topology library, it's pretty complex. As you're dealing with images and rectangles only, maybe you could use something more simple.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to be able to determine intersections and distances between bounding boxes. Assuming you have axis-aligned bounding boxes (AABB, i.e. the box rectangle edges being parallel to the axes), you can reduce the 2D computations to 1D interval relations -- computed the relations between the x and y intervals separately and combine them. This divide-and-conquer strategy should simplify the logic greatly.

Here is a class that you could use as starting point. It is quite untested and should not be used for production code -- I know it does not work for special cases such as empty intervals (min > max) or singleton interval (min == max) --, but it should help you get on your way.

```
package stackoverflow;

public enum IntervalRelation
{
    LEFT,
    LEFT_TOUCHING,
    OVERLAP_LEFT,
    CONTAINING,
    CONTAINED,
    OVERLAP_RIGHT,
    RIGHT_TOUCHING,
    RIGHT;

    public static double getIntervalDistance(
            double min1, double max1,
            double min2, double max2) {
        double maxOfMin = Math.max(min1, min2);
        double minOfMax = Math.min(max1, max2);

        return maxOfMin - minOfMax;
    }

    public static IntervalRelation between(
            double min1, double max1,
            double min2, double max2) {
        double dist = getIntervalDistance(min1, max1, min2, max2);

        if (dist > 0) {
            // not touching or intersecting
            return min1 < min2? LEFT : RIGHT;
        } else if (dist == 0) {
            // touching
            return min1 < min2? LEFT_TOUCHING : RIGHT_TOUCHING;
        } else {
            // overlapping or containment
            if (min1 < min2) {
                // overlap left or containing
                return max1 < max2? OVERLAP_LEFT : CONTAINING;
            } else {
                return max1 < max2? CONTAINED : OVERLAP_RIGHT;
            }
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(between( 0.0,+1.0, -2.0,-1.0));
        System.out.println(between( 0.0,+1.0, +2.0,+3.0));
        System.out.println(between( 0.0,+1.0, -2.0,+0.0));
        System.out.println(between( 0.0,+1.0, +1.0,+3.0));
        System.out.println(between( 0.0,+1.0, +0.5,+1.5));
        System.out.println(between( 0.0,+1.0, -0.5,+0.5));
        System.out.println(between( 0.0,+1.0, -0.5,+1.5));
        System.out.println(between( 0.0,+1.0, +0.5,+0.6));
    }
}
```

In general, I found it *very* helpful to provide `Interval` classes instead of always having to provide min/max argument pairs and having to check for emptiness or singletonness.